# Error message when placing order with only bundle products?

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, place-order, magento2.2.8

On my **Magento 2.2.8** store I get the following error message when I place an order with bundle products that only have virtual products as bundled products.

```
{"message":"Auf dem Server ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte versuchen Sie die Bestellung erneut aufzugeben.","trace":"#0 \/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(6953, Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n#1 \/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...', Array)\n#2 \/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(6953, Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n#3 \/html\/magento2\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Checkout\/Model\/PaymentInformationManagement\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, Array)\n#4 [internal function]: Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(6953, Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n#5 \/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#6 \/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/module-webapi\/Controller\/Rest.php(244): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#7 \/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8 \/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#9 \/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#10 \/html\/magento2\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Webapi\/Controller\/Rest\/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#11 \/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(136): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12 \/html\/magento2\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#13 \/html\/magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#14 \/html\/magento2\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#15 {main}"}
```

The error means something like: `There was an error on the server. Please try to replace your order.` I can see `savePaymentMethod` in the trace, so maybe thats related? The order is placed anyway, I can see it in the order grid in admin, but on frontend it looks like it hasnt.

Thanks for any help!